# jQuery - Remove last item of multiple selects that starts with same ID

Tags: jquery

I have a table that has multiple rows. This table has in a column a `SELECT` that starts with `ID=next_(rowindex)`

What I need is when I button clicks the event to remove the last option of each `SELECT`.

I'm doing this right now but is not working because is removing the last option of the last SELECT.

```
$("select[id^='next_'] option").last().remove();
```

And what I need is that all SELECT elements have the same items, so each one gets the last item removed.

Any clue?

Comment: Same thing. It gets removed only the last item of the last SELECT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove last option of multiple select, use this code:

```
$("select[id^='next_'] option:last-child").remove();
```

It will select the last option child of all select with id that begins with 'next_', and remove it.

Comment: That's good to hear. I'm happy to help. :)